# How to Identify ID of containers(4 words and 7 digits) at one string in EDI code file using notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, edi

The ID of each container consists of 4 words and 7 digits( in EDI files  -no space between. )
At the code there are strings of 11 digits that match the expression as well.
The expression has the form:

```
(\w{4}\d{7})
```

And this not fully solve matching due to letters and digits.
link for demo: https://regex101.com/r/vwH9nH/4
Another  expression more closer to match is:

```
([A-Z]{4}d{7})
```

This seem to be  more specified closer but not match to notepad++  to express container's ID.

In notepad++ I try:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find What: `(([A-Z]{4}d{7})h*|(?s:.)` **defined ID of containers**

  - Replace with: `(?1$1\n:)`
  - check Wrap around
  - check Regular expression
  - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

#### Here is part of code to copy notepad++:

`UNB+UNOA:2+RCW OPS CENTER+TERMINAL+180808:1519+1533741570C3ED+++++RCW OPS CENTER'UNH+01533741570BAP+BAPLIE:D:95B:UN:SMDG22'BGM++CAPSTAN4.20180808151930+9'DTM+137:1808081519UTC:301'TDT+20+081S+++HSD:172:166+++9V7575:103:ZZZ:MONTE VERDE'LOC+5+BRSSA:139:6'LOC+61+COCTG:139:6'DTM+178:1808090412:201'DTM+133:1808091512:201'DTM+132:1808180041:201'RFF+VON:081N'LOC+147+0380412::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29515'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+DOHAI:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+SUDU8505087+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+HSD:172:20'LOC+147+0380312::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29586'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+DOCAU:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+UACU5363691+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+HLC:172:20'LOC+147+0380212::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29591'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+COCTG:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+TGHU9702812+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+MSC:172:20'LOC+147+0380112::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29616'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+DOCAU:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+HLXU6240079+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+HLC:172:20'LOC+147+0380414::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29476'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+PRSJU:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+HASU4556735+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+HSD:172:20'LOC+147+0380314::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29476'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+DOHAI:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+SUDU6787839+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+HSD:172:20'LOC+147+0380214::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29481'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+COCTG:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+TGHU9861619+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+MSC:172:20'LOC+147+0380114::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29492'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+COCTG:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+HASU5014810+45G1+++5'NAD+CA+HSD:172:20'LOC+147+0301582::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29123'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+COCTG:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+CLHU4693498+42G1+++5'NAD+CA+MSC:172:20'LOC+147+0301482::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29160'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+PECLL:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+TCLU4424005+42G1+++5'NAD+CA+HLC:172:20'LOC+147+0301382::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29183'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+COCTG:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+...`

In this matching and replacing I have only one empty line:
and I want to have all containers in one column.

My expected output to be:

```
SUDU8505087
UACU5363691
TGHU9702812
HLXU6240079
HASU4556735
SUDU6787839
TGHU9861619
HASU5014810
CLHU4693498
TCLU4424005
```

Comment: Do you mean you tried `(([A-Z]{4}\d{7})\h*|(?s:.)`? Some escapes are missing.

Comment: What is your exact problem? The regex looks working. What empty line do you mean?

Comment: Yes You are right I forgot or overlooked that .Escape to be before "d"- It looks You solve my issue and all working   -Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
.*?([A-Z]{4}\d{7})((?![A-Z]{4}\d{7}).)*
```

by

```
$1\n
```

and get

```
SUDU8505087
UACU5363691
TGHU9702812
HLXU6240079
HASU4556735
SUDU6787839
TGHU9861619
HASU5014810
CLHU4693498
TCLU4424005
```

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I tested  and  working very  well. The first capture   group & 2dn group  with or without pipes are give same result-thanks for alternative Yours helpful solution .

Comment: @AndrzejOrlecki, it the problem is solved, accept an answer by clicking a checkmark on the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.*?([A-Z]{4}\d{7})
```

by

```
$1\n
```

and get

```
SUDU8505087
UACU5363691
TGHU9702812
HLXU6240079
HASU4556735
SUDU6787839
TGHU9861619
HASU5014810
CLHU4693498
TCLU4424005
+42G1+++5'NAD+CA+HLC:172:20'LOC+147+0301382::5'MEA+WT++KGM:29183'LOC+9+BRSSA:139:6+TECSV'LOC+11+COCTG:139:6+TCC'LOC+83+COCTG:139:6'RFF+BM:1'EQD+CN+...
```

Then remove the last line by hand.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Working as well even  last line to be removed by hand